# How to mock a void private method to throw Abstract Exception with Powermock?

Tags: junit, powermockito

While writing unit test case for method **someMethod1**, I have a use case where I'm trying to ensure that an **abstract exception** (**AnalysisException**) is thrown when method (**someMethod2**) is called. Class under test is **JdbcTemplateSampleImpl** .

```
public class JdbcTemplateSampleImpl {

   public void someMethod1() {
      someMethod2();
   }

   private void someMethod2() throws AnalysisException  {
    // some code here
   }
}
```

I am using **PowerMockito** to do like this

```
@Test(expected = com.test.AnalysisException.class)
public void abstractClassExceptionCheck2Test1()  throws Throwable  {
    JdbcTemplateSampleImpl jdbcTemplateSampleImpl1 = 
              PowerMockito.spy(jdbcTemplateSampleImpl0);
    PowerMockito.doThrow(mock(AnalysisException.class)).
             when(jdbcTemplateSampleImpl1,"classCheck2");    
    jdbcTemplateSampleImpl1.abstractClassExceptionCheck2();
}
```

But while executing test case , i'm getting an error like this

**java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected "com.test.AnalysisException" but was "java.lang.NullPointerException"**

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`. Maybe it's not thrown by `classCheck2`.

Answer (score 0):

Mock the exception outside of the `doThrow` method call.

```
AnalysisException e = mock(AnalysisException.class);
PowerMockito.doThrow(e).
         when(jdbcTemplateSampleImpl1,"classCheck2");
```

Comment: Stii it is throwing the same exception ,